# How can make a menu with two or more options when I `click` on `FileBox` object?

Tags: kivy

How can make a menu with two or more options when I `click` on `FileBox` object in below code? Plesae have a look on the attached pic if you don't know what I mean.

**CODE**

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
kv = """


<FileBox>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.337, 0.760, 0.968, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

RelativeLayout:
    FileBox:
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

"""

class FileBox(BoxLayout):



    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FileBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.oryg_text = ''

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.button == 'right':
            print('DROP A MENU\n Delete \n Copy')

    def function_called_from_drop_menu(self, choosed):
        print('CHOOSED', choosed)

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class NewApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Drop Menu'
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NewApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John must have answered while I was looking at the question. John's answer is perfectly reasonable. My answer is a bit different because it depends on Popup.

[image]

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
kv = """


<FileBox>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.337, 0.760, 0.968, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

RelativeLayout:
    FileBox:
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

<MenuPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Delete"
            on_press: print("Delete")
        Button:
            text: "Copy"
            on_press: print("Copy")
"""

class MenuPopup(Popup):
    pass

class FileBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FileBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.oryg_text = ''

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch.pos)
        if touch.button == 'right':
            print('DROP A MENU\n Delete \n Copy')
            popup = MenuPopup(title='Menu',
            auto_dismiss=True,
            size_hint=(None, None), 
            size=(180, 180),
            pos_hint={'x': touch.pos[0] / Window.width, 
                        'y':(touch.pos[1] - self.height)/  Window.height})
            popup.open()

    def function_called_from_drop_menu(self, choosed):
        print('CHOOSED', choosed)

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class NewApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Drop Menu'
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NewApp().run()
```

**Update**

If you don't like the frame by Popup you can also use the class on which Popup is based. It is called `ModalView`. You also need to delete the title since ModalView has no title.

[image]

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
kv = """


<FileBox>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.337, 0.760, 0.968, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

RelativeLayout:
    FileBox:
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

<MenuPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Delete"
            on_press: print("Delete")
        Button:
            text: "Copy"
            on_press: print("Copy")
"""

class MenuPopup(ModalView):
    pass

class FileBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FileBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.oryg_text = ''

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch.pos)
        if touch.button == 'right':
            print('DROP A MENU\n Delete \n Copy')
            popup = MenuPopup(
            auto_dismiss=True,
            size_hint=(None, None), 
            size=(180, 180),
            pos_hint={'x': touch.pos[0] / Window.width, 
                    'y':(touch.pos[1] - self.height)/  Window.height})
            popup.open()

    def function_called_from_drop_menu(self, choosed):
        print('CHOOSED', choosed)

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class NewApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Drop Menu'
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NewApp().run()
```

Comment: Your approach looks better than a simple `DropDown`.

Comment: Yes, thats really close to what I need.  The only thing I need to work out is how to get rid of  `popup`  frame around `buttons`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a `DropDown` is attached to a `Button`, but that is not necessary. You can create the `DropDown` as described in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html#basic-example) and instead of binding it to a `Button` to open it, you can just call `open()` in your `on_touch_down()` method. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown

Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
kv = """


<FileBox>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.337, 0.760, 0.968, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

RelativeLayout:
    FileBox:
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

"""

class FileBox(BoxLayout):



    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FileBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.oryg_text = ''

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.button == 'right':
            print('DROP A MENU\n Delete \n Copy')

            # create the DropDown
            self.dropdown = DropDown(auto_dismiss=False)

            # add Buttons
            btn = Button(text='Delete', size_hint_y=None, height=44)
            btn.bind(on_release=self.function_called_from_drop_menu)
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)

            btn = Button(text='Copy', size_hint_y=None, height=44)
            btn.bind(on_release=self.function_called_from_drop_menu)
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)

            # open the DropDown
            self.dropdown.open(self)

    def function_called_from_drop_menu(self, choosed):
        print('CHOOSED', choosed)

        # dismiss the DropDown
        self.dropdown.dismiss()

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class NewApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Drop Menu'
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NewApp().run()
```